# Gtk+ GtkComboBox insert GtkWidget instead of strings

Tags: c++, c, gtk

Good day

I'm new to Gtk+ and I want to use GtkComboBox to create a custome combobox where I can insert a gtk widget (which has a table, and a couple of buttons) inside the combobox. is that possible or not using gtk+ under C.
I'm using Gtk 2.10.4

if that is not possible, can you please suggest another way to implement that

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to put `GtkWidget`s into `GtkComboBox`. The combo box allows you to use `GtkCellRenderer`s into the popup, but they are not `GtkWidget`s although you may find a `GtkCellRenderer` which suits your needs.

Alternatively, you could write your own custom `GtkCellRenderer` which does the same as the widget, or if you can't do that, you'll have to roll your own `GtkComboBox`-alike widget that does popup a window containing `GtkWidget`s

Comment: I did the later, I wrote my own GtkComboBox alike widget :)